# Symfony 3.1 Nested forms. How do I customize?

Tags: forms, symfony

working with Symfony3.1 and its Form component.

Let me ask for a toy example with  entities Alpha, Beta, Gamma, where Alpha 1:M Beta 1:M Gamma.

I wish to render a nested edit form as a unordered list, something like

[image]

where: AlphaType defines:

```
$builder ->add('title', TextType::class)
         ->add('betas', CollectionType::class, array(
         'entry_type' => BetaType::class,
         .....
             ));
```

BetaType defines:

```
$builder ->add('title')
         ->add('gammas', CollectionType::class, array(
         'entry_type' => GammaType::class,
          .....
            ));
```

and GammaType defines:

```
$builder->add('title');
```

I tried something like

```
<ul>
 {{ form_start(edit_form) }}
    {{ form_errors(edit_form) }}

  <li> {{ form_row(edit_form.title) }} 
  <ul> <li>{{ form_row(edit_form.betas.children.0.title) }} 
  <ul> <li> {{form_row(edit_form.betas.children.0.gammas.children.0.title) }} </li> </ul></ul></li>

{{ form_end(edit_form) }} </ul>
```

which it does not work, since it render just a single subobject to edit (you could have more)

Comment: When I face this problem, I always follow the instructions from: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html  It's pretty straightforward.

Comment: @Oscar. Yes, it is my main reference. But it seems to me that it is not so straightforward if you wish a edit page, such that a user may  add a new subobjects too. I see the link to the [Symfony Collection jQuery Plugin](https://github.com/ninsuo/symfony-collection), but I am trying to understand how to do by myself.